# How to change the Circuit Diagram to indicated a connection to a sourcemeter?

Tags: transistors

I have 2 circuit diagrams representing the connection of a transistor.
However in reality the Current/Voltage source and Current/Voltage meter are done with a **SourceMeter**. 
How do I modify the circuit to accurately indicate that the Transitor is connected to a SourceMeter?

The following circuit diagram represents a TFT where we are:

1. Passing a voltage (with SMU) between Source and Gate (VGS)
2. Passing a voltage (with SMU) between Source and Drain (VDS)
3. Measuring current (IDS)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPS378.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The second circuit diagram represents a TFT where we:

1. Shorted the Drain with the Gate (VDS)
2. Are passing a current (IDS)
3. Are measuring the Voltage (VDS=VGS since it is shorted)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDn7gL.png)</sup>

How do I change it to indicate that I am using a Sourcemeter? 
And also how would I show that the SourceMeter is connected to a PC, or is it redundant?

Comment: Do it whatever way will be clear to your audience, whoever that is. I'd probably just make a box and label it "SourceMeter" or "SMU". And annotate with the supplied voltage.

Comment: The Amp meter goes in series and V meter in parallel

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 could you show me how you would draw it? ii think I just remove the ampmetre connection to the ground right ?

Comment: No. It goes in series in the loop of 1)power source, 2)load and 3)drain.  Where are 1,2?

Comment: 1) the power source is IDS, 2) the load is the tranistor so channel between source (connected to ground) and drain